# How do I move elements within their grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://codepen.io/tphelps5/pen/GRgBMMZ

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
      
let reset = document.querySelector(".reset");


function resetOutput() {
  output.innerHTML = "0";
}
```

```css
* {
  background-color: silver;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

#calc_buttons {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 50vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(6);
}

#calc_buttons > button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #6699cc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}

#calc_buttons > button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}
```

```html
<h1> My First JavaScript Calculator </h2>
  <div id="calculator">
<div id="calc_display">
  <span id="output"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="calc_buttons">
    <button onclick="resetOutput()" id="num" class="reset" data-equals="reset">C</button>
    
    <button id="num" class="seven">7</button>
    <button id="num" class="eight">8</button>
    <button id="num" class="nine">9</button>
    
    <button id="num" class="four">4</button>
    <button id="num" class="five">5</button>
    <button id="num" class="six">6</button>
    
    <button id="num" class="three">3</button>
    <button id="num" class="two">2</button>
    <button id="num" class="one">1</button>
    
  
    <button id="num" class="zero">0</button>
    
   <button id="num" class="decimal" data-action="decimal">.</button>
   <button id="num" class="equals" data-equals="equal">=</button>
   <button id="num" class="minus" data-action="minus">-</button>
   <button id="num" class="plus" data-action="plus">+</button>
   <button id="num" class="divide" data-action="divide">/</button>
   <button id="num" class="multiply" data-action="multiply">*</button>
</div>
```

I am working on a calculator app and I am trying to move the numbers down a row. I want the "C" or "Reset" button on the top row by itself and the following rows as, "7, 8, 9, *" "4, 5, 6, -" "1, 2, 3 +" "0, ., ="

Does anyone have any ideas on how to move these elements more easily? I know I can move them around with margins, but I know there must be a simpler way to complete this challenge. Thank you!

Comment: `grid-column: span 4;` to the C button ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css:

```
.reset {
    grid-column: span 4;
}
```

And sort the buttons like this:

```
<button id="num" class="seven">7</button>
<button id="num" class="eight">8</button>
<button id="num" class="nine">9</button>

<button id="num" class="multiply" data-action="multiply">*</button>

<button id="num" class="four">4</button>
<button id="num" class="five">5</button>
<button id="num" class="six">6</button>

<button id="num" class="minus" data-action="minus">-</button>

<button id="num" class="three">3</button>
<button id="num" class="two">2</button>
<button id="num" class="one">1</button>

<button id="num" class="plus" data-action="plus">+</button>

<button id="num" class="zero">0</button>

<button id="num" class="decimal" data-action="decimal">.</button>
<button id="num" class="equals" data-equals="equal">=</button>
<button id="num" class="divide" data-action="divide">/</button>
```

https://codepen.io/zuyas/pen/XWJPPqM

And as a note: You should switch your id and class values. Ids must be unique.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood, You can use *:nth-child(-n + x)* to select groups of children and set them on a row or column instead filtering them individually .

example

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
      
let reset = document.querySelector(".reset");


function resetOutput() {
  output.innerHTML = "0";
}
```

```css
* {
  background-color: silver;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

#calc_buttons {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 50vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(6);
 
}

#calc_buttons > button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #6699cc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}

#calc_buttons > button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}
button:nth-child(-n + 13 ) {
grid-row:5;
}
button:nth-child(-n + 10 ) {
grid-row:4;
}button:nth-child(-n + 7 ) {
grid-row:3;
}
button:nth-child(-n + 4 ) {
grid-row:2;
} 
button:nth-child(1) {
grid-row:1;
}
button:nth-child(13) ~button, #calc_buttons:before {
grid-column:4
}
/* a pseudo for laziness and push last buttons 1 row down */
#calc_buttons:before {
content:'';
}
```

```html
<h1> My First JavaScript Calculator </h2>
  <div id="calculator">
<div id="calc_display">
  <span id="output"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="calc_buttons">
    <button onclick="resetOutput()" id="num" class="reset" data-equals="reset">C</button>
    
    <button id="num" class="seven">7</button>
    <button id="num" class="eight">8</button>
    <button id="num" class="nine">9</button>
    
    <button id="num" class="four">4</button>
    <button id="num" class="five">5</button>
    <button id="num" class="six">6</button>
    
    <button id="num" class="three">3</button>
    <button id="num" class="two">2</button>
    <button id="num" class="one">1</button>
    
  
    <button id="num" class="zero">0</button>
    
   <button id="num" class="decimal" data-action="decimal">.</button>
   <button id="num" class="equals" data-equals="equal">=</button>
   <button id="num" class="minus" data-action="minus">-</button>
   <button id="num" class="plus" data-action="plus">+</button>
   <button id="num" class="divide" data-action="divide">/</button>
   <button id="num" class="multiply" data-action="multiply">*</button>
</div>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child
>
> **`:nth-child(-n+3)`**
>
> Represents the first three elements. [=-0+3, -1+3, -2+3]

That was for info (and handy to know) , `since grid-column: span 4;` was already given in comment and in answer